# How can I remove the top white bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with a blank space (or bar) on the top of my website.

I have tried playing with different values of padding and position as some other posts suggests but nothing seems to work.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Hayao Miyazaki Tribute Page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="miyazaki.css">
</head>

<div id="main" class="image">
  <h1>Hayao Miyazaki</h1>
  <h2> “They say that the best blaze burns brightest when circumstances are at their worst.”</h2>
  <img alt="Miyazaki Black and White" src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/244942.jpg">
</div>

<body>

  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an running example in jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: any Website url?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Emanuele Hi, I tried and I came up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/y4tLrnka/ (Is this the right way to post a running example?) Thanks!

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks! This is an awesome resource, much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have given`position: absolute` to the `img`, you should specify the position of the image.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 230px;
  left: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}

img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0;
  top: 0; /* added position */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Hayao Miyazaki Tribute Page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="miyazaki.css">
</head>

<div id="main" class="image">
  <h1>Hayao Miyazaki</h1>
  <h2> “They say that the best blaze burns brightest when circumstances are at their worst.”</h2>
  <img alt="Miyazaki Black and White" src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/244942.jpg">
</div>

<body>

  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for all the suggestions and replies, all you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You should add margin 0 to body class

**css**

```
body{
background: #fff;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top:0;` to img tag.

```css
h1 {
font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
position: relative;
top: 150px;
left: 300px;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
color: white;
margin: 0;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
position: relative;
top: 230px;
left: 300px;
z-index: 2;
color: white;
font-weight: 100;
font-style: italic;
}

img {
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 0;
top: 0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Hayao Miyazaki Tribute Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="miyazaki.css">
</head>
<div id="main" class="image">
<h1>Hayao Miyazaki</h1>
<h2> “They say that the best blaze burns brightest when circumstances are at their worst.”</h2>
<img alt="Miyazaki Black and White" src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/244942.jpg">
</div>
<body>
<script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Avoid using `position:absolute;`. **Absolutely positioned elements have no awareness of what's happening around them.** When a page changes size, the elements don't move in relation to each other but rather in relation to their container and the values you've set for top, left etc.

To know more:https://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/

In your case just put that  image as background to the division and place the text h1,h2 inside the division and add padding(if required) to the h1,h2 to align them.